# how to show other attribute in active record validation messsage

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I was using `ActiveRecord` validations, with custom error messages.The problem I came across is I want to show one more attribute in the error message. For example following code only shows value on which validation is running.

```
class Coffee < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :size, inclusion: { in: %w(small medium large),
    message: "%{value} is not a valid size" }
end
```

Can I also show type(assuming type is a field in Coffee table), following both attempts doesn't work:

```
class Coffee < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :size, inclusion: { in: %w(small medium large),
    message: "%{value} is not a valid size for type: %{type}" } #`method_missing': undefined local variable or method `type'
    message: "%{value} is not a valid size for type: #{type}" } #Error: i18n::MissingInterpolationArgument
end
```

Versions:

```
ActiveRecord: 3.1.6
Ruby: ruby-1.9.3-p429
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`lambda`** like this

```
class Coffee < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :size, inclusion: { in: %w(small medium large), :message=> lambda { |e| "#{e.size} is not a valid size for type #{e.type}"}

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a custom validation

```
class Coffee < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :size_for_type

  def size_for_type
    unless %w(small medium large).include?(size)
      errors.add(:size, "%{value} is not a valid size for type: #{type}")
    end
  end
end
```